# How to protect local branch with PhpStorm?

Tags: git, version-control, ide, phpstorm

The idea is easy. I need to set some local branches as **protected / non-pushable** while they are not "master" or protected on origin.

Same idea already exists in PhpStorm Settings menu as comma separated list of branches which are prohibited to force pushes.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In phpstorm, there is no any ways to achieve this feature now. But you can vote your voice [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/feedback/feedback.jsp?product=PhpStorm)